# Let X be a subset of M. Let x be in M. Prove that if x is in the closure of X, then the intersection of the epsilon ball around x and X is non empty.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let X be a subset of M.  Let x be in M. Prove that if x is in the closure of X, then the intersection of the epsilon ball around x and X is non empty.

I have that the epsilon ball and X are both non empty for some y, but I can't see how they would imply that y is in the closure of X.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to prove the converse of what you are actually supposed to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Being in the closure $\overline{X}$ of some set $X$ in a metric space means that there exists some sequence $(x_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset X$ and some $x\in\overline{X}$ such that $x_{k}\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}x\in\overline{X}$.

By definition of a limit in a metric space, you can rewrite that by $\forall\epsilon,\exists N_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb{N}:\forall k\geq N_{\epsilon}: d(x_{k},x)<\epsilon$.

By definition of an epsilon ball $B(x,\epsilon):=\left\{y\in M\left.\right\vert\,d(x,y)<\epsilon\right\}$, it means that $x_{k}\in B(x,\epsilon)$ for all $k\geq N_{\epsilon}$ and since $x_{k}\in X$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the intersection $X\cap B(x,\epsilon)\neq\emptyset$ because it contains at least the set $\{x_{k}\vert k\geq N_{\epsilon}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B(x,\epsilon)\cap X =\varnothing$. Then $M\backslash B(x,\epsilon)$ is a closed set containing $X$ and not containing $x$. This contradicts the fact that $x$ is in the closure of $X$.