# The definition of a limit point

Tags: real-analysis

I may just be having a bad thinking day. Haha but why in the definition does the (open ball centered at x with radius r intersect A without the set of x equal the empty set?

Comment: That's not the right definition.

Answer (score 0):

A limit point of a set $A$ in a metric space $(M,d)$ is a point $x\in M$ such that there exists a sequence $(x_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{k}\in A\setminus\{x\},\,\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_{k}\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}x$. So any ball, with $\epsilon>0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ as proved in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498742/let-x-be-a-subset-of-m-let-x-be-in-m-prove-that-if-x-is-in-the-closure-of-x-t/1498767#1498767)

Edit: corrected because of the right comment below ($x_{k}$ needs to be in $A\setminus\{x\}$, not in $A$).

Comment: You need $x_k \in A \setminus \{x\}.$